# High Chart inserting data from arrays into line graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I'm having trouble finding a way to insert data from an array I get from another function in my javascript file into my line graph. I just want to make sure this is supported and I don't have to switch to a different graphing package. Here is my current code, I'm guessing you have to add in a for loop into the data series, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

```
function displayGraph(){
   //data to insert
   var x =new Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4); //array of x coordinates
   var y =new Array(1, 1.8, 1.5, 2.5, 6.3);//array of y coordinates

$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Glaicer Elevations',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'xAxis'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'yAxis'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'km'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
         // want to insert another data series using outside arrays
            series: [{
                name: 'Line1',
                data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]
            }]

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can alter the function, the you should prepare data in the right format. Sth like the sample data in your example.
If you cannot, then make a for loop to prepare the data. Sth like this:

```
   xy= [];
   for(var i in x) {
      xy[i] = [x[i],y[i]];
   }
```

Comment: Once I prepare the data like this, how would I then call it to graph it in the data: tag?

Comment: I renamed it to xy, so you do not have any conflicts. You simple set `data:xy`